# Can't draw bitmap in layer-list

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

I am trying to create a compound background adding `shape drawable` and search icon from `Android Studio`'s vector asset. But instead of the search icon, it draws something indicating an error.

[image]

Here is my drawable file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:width="44dp" android:height="24dp" android:gravity="center">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/parcel_indicator_corner_radius"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorAccent"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:gravity="center" android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Does anybody have ideas why search icon might not be visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is here

set the `android:drawable` property for an item instead of setting up the **Bitmap**

```
 <item android:gravity="center" android:width="24dp" android:height="24dp">
    <bitmap android:src="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp" />
</item>
```

**Replace with**

```
 <item
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ic_search_white_24dp"
    android:gravity="center">

</item>
```

Comment: Working. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I can't add a comment, so I'll leave this as an answer.

The search icon is not visible because you probably used a vector asset. The `bitmap` tag is for bitmaps, e.g. pngs.